# Are questions like "Does my phonology look naturalistic" allowed here? If not, why not?

Tags: discussion, on-topic, scope, asking-questions

Are questions* like "Does my phonology look naturalistic", "How can I improve my phonology (to make it look more naturalistic)" and "How can I evolve my phonology" allowed here? It seems, at first glance, that these type of questions are too subjective, but investigating what's wrong with a phonological system is educative.

Naturally, simple answers like 'do this' are wrong, and answers should not contain *what to do* but *how to do it*, talking about kitchen-sinkness, balance in phonological systems (and mass changes and chains that might occur there), phoneme occurence in systems and Euro-/Anglocentricism.

Furthermore, many new conlangers ask these questions (see [/r/conlangs's SD](https://www.reddit.com/r/conlangs/comments/841sio/small_discussions_46_20180312_to_0325/)) and can give the conlang SE more questions and views, as [Area 51 stats](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/101265/constructed-languages) show that the SE 'needs work'.

---

*Example:
Proposed Q:

> ### How natural my phonology?
>
> This is my phonology for my language examplang.
> `PLOSIVE     | p b |      t d | k g |`
> `NASAL       |     |          |     |`
> `FRICATIVE   | f v | θ    s   | x   |`
> `APPROXIMANT |     |       ɹ  |  w  |`
> `FLAP/TAP    |     |       ɾ  |     |`
>
> `| i y     u`
> `|  e`      
> `|   ɛ   ɔ`
> `|    a`

Ideal A:

> There are a couple things to notice. First, balance. The only voiced fricative is /v/, which is very unbalanced (although there *are exceptions* [with link]) and via sound changes, it might be removed or other voiced fricatives added. Then, the only front rounded vowel is /y/ and the Close-Mid row misses a back.
>
> Then, occurrence. Less than 2% of languages have no nasal stops (Maddieson, Ian. 2008. Absence of Common Consonants. Accessed online at http://wals.info/feature/18). Also, /j l/ look quite common in a system like yours.
>
> Common sound changes to evolve your phonological systems are: a chain in the vowels (which partially will fix irregularities), voicing when intervocalically (Old English had /f s ʃ h/ (or /x/), and borrowing /v/ from French added /v z ʒ/ due to balance), adding diphthongs via gemination (i.e. `Vr > V[+gem]`, then `a: > ai`, `e: > ei`, `ɔ: > o` (fixing unbalance), `i: y: > i` (later inducing merger between /i y/ too) and use those diphthongs to get glides).

A different question may have been answered including Anglo-/Eurocentricism, kitchen-sinkness and relex.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Questions asking for value judgements should be closed as Primarily Opinion Based. This includes your (original) example question.
2. Questions can however ask how **naturalistic** a conlang's phonology system is. Questions do have to **explicitly** ask this though, don't interpret a question asking if their phonology looks good as meaning whether it is naturalistic.
3. Questions about diachronic phonology are okay, but many would be duplicates of [What is an overview of sound changes?](https://conlang.stackexchange.com/q/221/113) Hopefully we'll get some more narrow diachronic questions which can build on the general overview.

Comment: See revised question. Would that be fine?

Comment: @DuncanWhyte Sure. What would make you think it wouldn't be?

Comment: Nothing, I was just wondering. Many new conlangers ask these type of questions and can help our userbase.